# Broken breeze.js.labs bower package

Tags: breeze

It seems there is a breaking change to the name of the bower package (https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.labs/commit/193e79443918c3836699aa06a0545e101f44d54d).

It looks like the name of the bower package was changed from `breeze.js.labs` to `breeze-client-labs`. I didn't see anything documented in any of the recent release notes.

This is causing my build to fail since the `bower.json` file still references `breeze.js.labs` and not `breeze-client-labs`.

I would expect the old package to remain to prevent from breaking peoples builds.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're catching us in release transition. Haven't prepared release notes yet. Just days away.

However, the breeze.js.labs github repo never served a bower package before. There was a "breeze.js.labs" bower package served out of a different github repo. It hadn't been updated in months and frankly I don't know what it held. It was not official. It was not ours. We had no responsibility for it. I asked the owner to give it up and he did (for which we are grateful).

I also note that "breeze labs" warns you that it is never to be regarded as stable or permanent. That's not a license to break you for the fun of it but it it gives us more leeway than we have in breeze core.

The net of it is that I'm sorry for the inconvenience .. and that's as far as that goes.

Moving forward, there are 2 packages to consider: breeze-client and breeze-client-labs. Please adjust accordingly.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks Ward for responding. It wasn't clear that the "breeze.js.labs" package wasn't official so I could see how this could happen. I've adjusted to use the new packages and it's all good now. There are certainly lots of moving parts that are outside the control of the developer that have to be carefully considered these days;)